# How to download a .rdp file in firefox without download prompt using Selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, rdp, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-profile

I am automating a web application which downloads an .rdp file on clicking a link.

1. I have added the following code to set profile,

   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "K://Automation//geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64//geckodriver.exe");
       DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
       FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",false)
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","K:\Automation");
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.downloadDir","K:\Automation");
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder","K:\Automation");
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","applicatiion/rdp, application/x-java-jnlp-file , text/anytext ,text/plain,text/html,application/plain");
       firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/force-download")
       cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS,true)
       cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,firefoxProfile)
       driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);

   2.I am still geting this prompt,[The firefox prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pj04.png)

Comment: 1. create manualy new Firefox profile 2. proceed downloading a rdp file manualy in the new Firefox profile and check in the option 'Do this automaticaly ...' 3. load selenium in the new Firefox profile https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

Comment: I am trying to automate the whole process, the automation runs on a remote server and we cannot manually create the profile on Firefox every time the setup is deployed.

Comment: Proceed the steps 1 and 2 localy 3. move the Firefox profile folder to your project 4. as previous 3 but load the Firefox profile from project instead of the remote server.